# Sql error Unknown column in field list

Tags: php, sql

I'm generating questions from sql database. I'm trying to save each answer with the question id.

I'm getting this error: "Error: Unknown column 'answer_text' in 'field list'" How come?

```
 //save text input to sql with question id and question answer
 $question_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_id']);

 foreach ($_POST['answer_text'] as $question_id => $answer_id){

        $sql="INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer_text)
                VALUES ({$question_id}, {$answer_id})";

echo $sql;

                  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
  }
 mysqli_close($con);

// generate question from database
if ($result) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $body = $row['question_body'];
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
    echo '<div class="questions-4">';
    echo '  
        <tr>
                <td>'.$body.'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="answer_text['.$question_id.']" </td><br>

         </tr>';
         echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
        $sql="INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer_value)
                VALUES ({$question_id}, '$answer_id')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and have not quoted the values you're using in the query. You're generating the equivalent of:

```
INSERT ... VALUES(foo, bar)
```

instead of

```
INSERT ... VALUES('foo', 'bar');
```

At bare minimum, to fix your immediate problem, you should have

```
VALUES ('{$question_id}', '{$answer_id}')";
        ^--------------^--^------------^--- these
```

Comment: i tried it but: 
 
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11', 'c')' at line 2